# Sqlalchemy two filters vs one and

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

This is a straight forward question. What is better to use, two `filters` or one `and_`? Is there any difference?

```
session.query(Test).filter(Test.id == X).filter(Test.test == Y).all()
```

**vs**

```
session.query(Test).filter(and_(Test.id == X, Test.test == Y)).all()
```

They will give me the same result but is there any difference i speed or anything else?

Comment: No meaningful difference (in the example given).

Comment: @IljaEverilä This is just a simple example to show what i mean (minimal code). But what if there where more(10+,20+) filters or ands_?

Comment: The usual answer to "difference in speed" is: measure it. The thing is that both have their uses. You cannot express some things with just `Query.filter()` that you can with `and_()` (easily, without De Morgan's).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Both queries in your question have the same performance. You can test this easily by inspecting the resulting SQL query.

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, and_
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm.query import Query

Base = declarative_base()

class Test(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    test = Column(String(50))


print(Query([Test]).filter(Test.id == 1).filter(Test.test == 'foo'))

# SELECT test.id AS test_id, test.test AS test_test
# FROM test
# WHERE test.id = :id_1 AND test.test = :test_1

print(Query([Test]).filter(and_(Test.id == 1, Test.test == 'foo')))

# SELECT test.id AS test_id, test.test AS test_test
# FROM test
# WHERE test.id = :id_1 AND test.test = :test_1
```

Both queries produce the same SQL expression.

[and_](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=and_#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.and_) is commonly used when you're using the SQL expression to query directly against tables, or when nesting multiple predicates within `or_`.